# How do I update record in mongoDB/Mongoose with case insensitive input

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am new to MongoDB/Mongoose, and I am having an issue with PUT request to update the phone number of name with duplicate entry.

**Objective**: My front end can take in person's name and its phone number. Whenever it takes in a name that already exist in our record, it will ask user if they want to replace the number. Furthermore, name input should be case insensitive, meaning as long as spelling is right, it should update the phone number.

e.g. If `{name: Test, number: 123}` exist in our record, inputting `{name: TEST, number: 456}` will provide a pop-up menu confirming if user want to change their name. If selected Ok, the record would change to `{name: Test, number:456}` while reflecting its change on front end side and on backend DB.

Currently, my schema is defined as following (on a different file).

```
const personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    number: String,
})
```

Current code for updating functionality is following, which does work for most part:

```
app.put('/api/persons/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    const body = req.body
    const person = {
        name: body.name,
        number: body.number,
    }

    Person.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, person, { new: true })
        .then(updatedPerson => res.json(updatedPerson))
        .catch(err => next(err))

    // catch is for error handling
})
```

**Main issue**: However, above code does not work when I input a name with same name but with different casing. For instance, Name "Test" and "TEST" is considered differently. Primary source of error, based on what I printed out on console, is that the ID is different and thus my code can't find the same entry.

i.e. ID for storing record with name "Test" is different from the ID of new entry `{name: TEST, number: 123}` and hence my input entry ID doesn't exit in my database.

Above is bit weird sense whenever I input the name with same case, it does work.

Based on some searching, I found a different stackoverflow suggestion that uses regex and `findoneandupdate`, so I tried the following:

```
app.put('/api/persons/:id', (req, res, next) => {

    const body = req.body
    const person = {
        name: body.name,
        number: body.number,
    }

    // for testing purpose,
    // this prints out the correct name
    Person.find({ name: new RegExp(`^${body.name}$`, `i`) })
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result[0])
        })

    Person.findOneAndUpdate({ name: new RegExp(`^${body.name}$`, `i`) }, person, { new: true })
        .then(updatePerson => {
            res.json(updatePerson)
        })
        .catch(err => next(err))
})
```

There was few issue with this:

1. Casing of person's name changes (so if the new input has name of "TEST", it will change it all caps when it is supposed to preserve the casing of initial entry)
2. Above worked via REST Client extension on VS code, which is similar to Postman. However actually testing on frontend had a same issue of not finding ID.

I was wondering what is the correct way to update the entry with either `findByIdAndUpdate` (preferably) or `findOneAndUpdate` while taking case insensitive entry and preserving the name.

For reference, following is what my front end looks like:
[image]

Comment: maybe you can convert the input all to lowercase?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a field query_name : String that is the lowercase version of the name.
I would use mongoose hooks.

```
const personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    number: String,
    original_name : String
})

personSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  this.query_name = this.name.toLowerCase();
  next();
});
```

You can read more about it and maybe find another solution here
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html

Note:
*Don't use arrow function because it does't have 'this' property.

Comment: Thanks for response! I went back and did some messing around with backend, and still had issue. However, it turns out that the issue was on frontend side, where checking for case sensitivity works but actual update process on frontend wasn't checking for it. 

It definitely caught me as a surprise, but it was easy to fix after that. Again, thank you for your response!